# The range of continuous functions and the Intermediate value theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$, $a<b$ and let $f$ be a continuous real valued function on $[a,b].$ Prove that if $f$ is one-to-one then $f([a,b])$ is either $[f(a),f(b)]$ or $[f(b),f(a)].$

Suppose $f(a)<f(b)$ then by the Intermediate Value Theorem (IVT) we have if $x\in(a,b)$ then $f(x)\in[f(a),f(b)].$ Arguing by contradiction suppose $f(x)<f(a)$ or $f(x)>f(b).$ If $f(x)<f(a)$ then by IVT $f([x,b])$ contains all points between $f(x)$ and $f(b)$ and contains $f(a)$ contradiction that $f$ is one-to-one.

Why does that contradict the assumption that $f$ is one-to-one?

Comment: A continuous and one-one function is necessarily monotone. Hence the range is either $[f(a), f(b)]$ or $[f(b), f(a)]$ depending on whether $f$ is increasing or decreasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(a) \in f([x,b])$, that means there is $y \in [x,b]$ so that $f(y) = f(a)$. Do you see why this cannot happen (if $f$ is one-to-one)?

Comment: But wouldn't $y$ just be $a$? So if $f(a) \in f([x,b])$ then we know by assumption there is a $a\in [x,b]$ such that $f(a) = a$ since $f(x) <f(a) <f(b)$.

Comment: We know $a<x<b$ and $x\leq y \leq b$ (if $f(a) \in f([x,b])$ so $y$ cannot be $a$.

Comment: Thank you, I see my mistake in reasoning now.